# How to invoke safari browser from wallet pass

Tags: ios, iphone, wallet

I am trying to invoke safari from wallet pass. I did not get any clue how doing these. For wallet pass to invoke a custom app its asking for the app store identifier. We are unable to find the app store Id for mobile safari application. Please help me with this.

Comment: Why not just add a hyperlink in a backfield?  You cannot use Safari as an associated app.

Comment: Hi There, When we open the pass through notification, the hyperlink doesn't work. Hyperlink works only when we access it from wallet app.

Comment: Yes, I agree that sucks from a design perspective.  We have long complained to Apple about this. It may be changing in iOS12, where in the current beta, users are asked to authenticate following a wallet notification, but that can’t be guaranteed until they release the GM build.  2 other solutions that may work are using Google Chrome, or directing to a Facebook page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my scenario is by using safari. Hope so, Apple will change it in iOS 12.